# How can I set label names manually on a loop springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a JSON array below, I want to be able to set label names that make sense instead of the entity names. Am generating tables dynamically using this data, I want the rows to have names that make more sense to the end user by assigning custom Label names.  the recordtype generates new tab names

This is my JSON

```
[
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "projectId": "USAID2020,
        "case": "2014",
        "recordType": "Identification",
        "itemDetails": [
            {
                "ItemValue": "023",
                "Label": "hA",
                "ItemValueLabel": "023",
                "Name": "hA"
            },
            {
                "ItemValue": "0005",
                "Label": "hUM",
                "ItemValueLabel": "0005",
                "Name": "hUM"
            },
            {
                "ItemValue": "5",
                "Label": "hCounty",
                "ItemValueLabel": "5",
                "Name": "hCounty"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "projectId": "USAID2020",
        "case": "2014",
        "recordType": "Eligibility",
        "itemDetails": [
            {
                "ItemValue": "023",
                "Label": "hA",
                "ItemValueLabel": "023",
                "Name": "hA"
            },
            {
                "ItemValue": "0005",
                "Label": "hUM",
                "ItemValueLabel": "0005",
                "Name": "hUM"
            },
            {
                "ItemValue": "0005",
                "Label": "hPUM",
                "ItemValueLabel": "0005",
                "Name": "hPUM"
            }
         
        ]
    }
]
```

This is how I want the labels to appear

```
[
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "projectId": "USAID2020,
        "case": "2014",
        "recordType": "Identification",
        "itemDetails": [
            {
                "ItemValue": "023",
                "Label": "Area Code",
                "ItemValueLabel": "023",
                "Name": "hA"
            },
            {
                "ItemValue": "0005",
                "Label": "Manager Identification",
                "ItemValueLabel": "0005",
                "Name": "hUM"
            },
            {
                "ItemValue": "5",
                "Label": "County Name",
                "ItemValueLabel": "5",
                "Name": "hCounty"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "projectId": "USAID2020",
        "case": "2014",
        "recordType": "Eligibility",
        "itemDetails": [
            {
                "ItemValue": "023",
                "Label": "Area Code",
                "ItemValueLabel": "023",
                "Name": "hA"
            },
            {
                "ItemValue": "0005",
                "Label": "Manager Identification",
                "ItemValueLabel": "0005",
                "Name": "hUM"
            },
            {
                "ItemValue": "0005",
                "Label": "House Code",
                "ItemValueLabel": "0005",
                "Name": "hPUM"
            }
         
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my logic

```
public ArrayList<Summary> getHouseHoldRecordsByCase(String country, String projectId, String case) {
        ArrayList<Summary> documents= new ArrayList<>();
        Summary summary = new Summary();
        ArrayList<ItemDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
       
        COVER cover = dataStoreService.getHouseHoldRecordsByCase(country, projectId, caseNumber);
        summary.case = caseNumber;
        summary.recordType = "Identification";
        summary.country = country;
        summary.projectId = projectId;
        Field[] fields = hsecover.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field _f:fields){
            try {
                String val = PropertyUtils.getProperty(hsecover, _f.getName()).toString();
                details.add(new ItemDetails(val, _f.getName(), val, _f.getName()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        summary.itemDetails = details;
        documents.add(summary);
        summary = new Summary();
        ELIGILITY elig = dataStoreService.getEliByCase(country, projectId, case);
        summary.recordType = "Eligibility";
        summary.case = case;
        summary.country = country;
        summary.projectId = projectId;
        details = new ArrayList<>();
        fields = elig.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field _f:fields){
            try {
                String val = PropertyUtils.getProperty(elig, _f.getName()).toString();
                details.add(new ItemDetails(val, _f.getName(), val, _f.getName()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        summary.itemDetails = details;
        documents.add(summary);
        }
        return documents;
    }

    public COVER getHouseHoldRecordsByCase(String country, String projectId, String case) {
        COVER usa = cover_repository.findByCase(case);
        return usa;
    }

    public ELIGILITY getEliByCase(String country, String projectId, String case) {
        ELIGILITY usa = eligility_repository.findByCaseNumber(case);
        return usa;
    }
```

My ItemDetails model class

```
public class ItemDetails {
    public String ItemValue;
    public String Label;
    public String ItemValueLabel;
    public String Name;

    public ItemDetails(String itemValue, String label, String itemValueLabel, String name) {
        ItemValue = itemValue;
        Label = label;
        ItemValueLabel = itemValueLabel;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

My Summary class

```
public class Summary {
    public String country;
    public String projectId;
    public String case;
    public String recordType;
    public ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemDetails;
}
```

The data comes from a database.

How can I set the label names with names that make sense instead of coming as entity names?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `@JsonProperty("different names")` on each fields
Or you can use `@JsonSetter("different name")` on setter method level.

Comment: Hi @Selvakumar how will I do have tried adding on the setter and getters no luck

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/renaming-properties.html

Comment: Follow above link you will get some idea